# Print the word after match from Perl array

Tags: perl

Array `@array` has

```
 Sex: M
 Name: John, oliver
 Age is 33
 Has no experience
 is 5 feet tall
```

I want to print the word after `Name:` which is John, oliver in this case.

Below code works on `$string`, how to do the same on an `@array`?

```
my ($name) = $string =~ /Name: (.+)$/;
print $name;
```

Comment: When displaying the content of a variable, it is a good idea to use `Data::Dumper`, so that people here know exactly what your data structure is.

Comment: Can you show the actual input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to [iterate over](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops) the array, apply the regex on each element. Something like:

```
my @array = ( 'Sex: M', 'Name: John, oliver', 'Age: 33' )
foreach my $item ( @array ) {
  if( $item =~ /Name: (.+)$/ ) {
    print $1;
  }
}
```

I think [hash](http://perl101.org/hashes.html) is a better datastructure to store your data.

Comment: thanks, edited the array content to show that hash cannot be used.

Answer (score 1):

To find results in an array, the tool for the job is `grep`.

```
foreach my $name_lines ( grep { m/Name/ } @array ) {
      my ($name) = /Name: (.+)$/;
      print $name,"\n"; 
}
```

Here I've assumed there might be multiple matches - you don't have to do that particularly though and could instead:

```
 my ($name) = map { m/Name: (.+$)/ } @stuff;
 print $name;
```

This uses `map` to transform the array, but because we assign it to a list containing a single scalar, the second match is discarded. (if there is one).

Although I'd suggest this isn't the best approach to take - an array of keys and values isn't particularly useful compared to a hash.

If you have an array:

```
my @stuff = ( "Sex: M",
 "Name: John, oliver", 
 "Age is 33",
 "Has no experience",
 "is 5 feet tall" );
```

Then you can transform it with `map`:

```
my %stuff_hash = map { /(\w+):? (.*)$/ } @stuff;
```

Which gives you a data structure looking like this:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'Age' => 'is 33',
          'Sex' => 'M',
          'is' => '5 feet tall',
          'Name' => 'John, oliver',
          'Has' => 'no experience'
        };
```

So you can:

```
print $stuff_hash{'Name'},"\n";
```

Or alternatively - stick your array back together into a string, and then multi line the regex:

```
my ($name) =   join ( "\n", @stuff) =~ m/Name: (.*)$/m;
print $name;
```

Answer (score 0):

### Let the structure fit your data

```
my @arr = (     
   {
      Sex => 'M',
      Name => 'John Doe',
      Age => 21,
   },
   {
      Sex => 'F',
      Name => 'Jane Doe',
      Age => 20,
   },
);
```

Then you can more easily find the data:

```
for (@arr){
   print "$_->{Name}\n";
}
```

Comment: Whilst probably true, this answer is essentially "If you want to go there, don't start from here". That's not always an option.

Comment: True. You posted a solution to the problem and mentioned to use another structure instead. I wanted to show such a structure.